# Unserialize from MySQL into a Multi-dimensional PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, serialization, multidimensional-array

I have a PHP/MySQL e-commerce site that is placing order detail information into a serialized array alongside customer address info.

I want to be able to pull out the order items field, unserialize it and then combine the order items into one master array of ALL ordered items that can be manipulated in order to count how many orders of a specific product have been made.

The arrays look like this when I print_r the unserialized rows. Below are two order arrays, one with 3 products, and the second with only one.

The array values are ID #, SKU #, Quantity, Product Name, Price.

I want to be able to combine ALL orders into one array and then sum the total quantities for each unique ID or SKU number.

I realize this type of thing is drop dead simple if the data was clean in MySQL, but such is life. Any thoughts on how to manipulate these arrays would be truly appreciated.

In this case want to end up with 4 arrays, with the 629/01-3600 ones being combined such that the quantity value is now 2

Many thanks.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => 488
            [5] => 23-1000
            [2] => 3
            [3] => PRODUCT NAME
            [4] => 2.50
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 423
            [5] => 24-2300
            [2] => 1
            [3] => PRODUCT NAME
            [4] => 3.50
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => 506
            [5] => 23-2800
            [2] => 1
            [3] => PRODUCT NAME
            [4] => 2.50
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [1] => 629
            [5] => 01-3600
            [2] => 1
            [3] => PRODUCT NAME
            [4] => 7.50
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => 629
            [5] => 01-3600
            [2] => 1
            [3] => PRODUCT NAME
            [4] => 7.50
        )

)
```

EDIT:

I wanted to add what eventually did what I was looking for

```
foreach($query->result as $row)
{
    $items[] = unserialize( $row['FIELDNAME'] );
}

foreach($items as $item)
{
    foreach($item as $order)
    {
        if( isset($output_array[$order[1]]) ) 
        {
            $output_array[$order[1]]['quantity'] += $order[2];
        }
        else
        {
            $output_array[$order[1]] = array (
                'name' => $order[3],
                'quantity' => $order[2],
                'sku' => $order[5]
                );
        }
    }
```

}

I then used this sorting function to sort on the quantity: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php#99419

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little bit of code so I've separated it into chunks.

This is my recreation of your two arrays. The last line puts them into one.

```
$items = array(
    array(
        1 => 488,
        5 => '23-1000',
        2 => 3,
        3 => 'PRODUCT NAME',
        4 => 2.50
      ),

    array(
        1 => 423,
        5 => '24-2300',
        2 => 1,
        3 => 'PRODUCT NAME',
        4 => 3.50
      ),

    array(
        1 => 506,
        5 => '23-2800',
        2 => 1,
        3 => 'PRODUCT NAME',
        4 => 2.50
      ),

    array(
        1 => 629,
        5 => '01-3600',
        2 => 1,
        3 => 'PRODUCT NAME',
        4 => 7.50
      )
  );

$array_2 = array(
    array(
        1 => 629,
        5 => '01-3600',
        2 => 1,
        3 => 'PRODUCT NAME',
        4 => 7.50
      )
  );

// Put the two arrays together (master array)
$new_array = array_merge($items, $array_2);
```

Next, we create two arrays to that will use the SKU# and another for the IDs.

```
// What the items will be sorted by
$skus = array();
$ids = array();
```

The more complicated part

```
// Loop through the combined items
foreach( $new_array as $item ) {

  /**
   * Check if the item's SKU number
   * has been added to the $skus array.
   * 
   * If it has then add the old qty with the current item's
   * 
   * Else, the item hasn't been added yet,
   * then add the entire item to the list
  */
  if( isset($skus[$item[5]]) ) {

    // If it exists, then add the new qty
    $skus[$item[5]][2] += $item[2];

  }else {

    // If it doesn't exist, then append it to the array
    $skus[$item[5]] = $item;
  }


  // Do the same thing as above
  // except for the id numbers
  if( isset($ids[$item[1]]) ) {

    // If it exists, then add the new qty
    $ids[$item[1]][2] += $item[2];

  }else {

    // If it doesn't exist, then append it to the array
    $ids[$item[1]] = $item;
  }
}
```

Make sure everything is the way you want it

```
echo '<h2>SKU Numbers</h2>';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($skus);
echo '</pre>';

echo '<h2>ID Numbers</h2>';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($ids);
echo '</pre>';
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT

For this code to work during the actual loop, you can try something like this. While I'm not completely sure if this will *work out of the box*, it should be a good place to start.

```
// What the items will be sorted by
$skus = array();
$ids = array();

foreach( $result as $row ) {

  $row = unserialize($row);

  /**
    * MODIFIED 
    * 
    * Check if the $row's SKU number
    * has been added to the $skus array.
    * 
    * If it has then add the old qty with the current $row's qty
    * 
    * Else, the $row hasn't been added yet,
    * then add the entire $row to the list
    */
  if( isset($skus[$row[5]]) ) {

    // If it exists, then add the new qty
    $skus[$row[5]][2] += $row[2];

  }else {

    // If it doesn't exist, then append it to the array
    $skus[$row[5]] = $row;
  }


  // Do the same thing as above
  // except for the id numbers
  if( isset($ids[$row[1]]) ) {

    // If it exists, then add the new qty
    $ids[$row[1]][2] += $row[2];

  }else {

    // If it doesn't exist, then append it to the array
    $ids[$row[1]] = $row;
  }

}
```

Comment: Actually, while I know this will work eventually. I am running a foreach($result as $row) loop in order to pull out the serialized fields and unserialize them. In order to merge say one hundred rows, I would need to create a new variable each time I loop through right? Then combine all hundred using array_merge?

Comment: I've added a change to my code (at the bottom) that gives an example on how to put the items into the $skus and $ids variables.